# Regex UTM google

Tags: r, regex, utm

I'm trying to extract a UTM from a Google link using [r](/questions/tagged/r), but my regex doesn't seem to work properly.

Here an example of a google link :

```
xxx/yyy?utm_medium=display&utm_source=ogury&utm_campaign=TOTO&zzz=coco
```

I tried the following regex to extract `TOTO`:

```
.+&utm_campaign=([[a-z]]+)&.+
```

with no success.

If someone can help, thanks!

Comment: What R-code did you try?

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern, `[[a-z]]+` is a malformed bracket expression, because it matches any char from the `[[a-z]` bracket expression (any lowercase ASCII letter or `[`) and then matches one or more `]` chars. You meant to use single `[` and `]` here.

You may use `sub` with the following regex:

```
sub(".*[&?]utm_campaign=([^&]+).*", "\\1", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oxt5XH/1).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `[&?]` - a `?` or `&`
- `utm_campaign=` - a literal substring
- `([^&]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `&` chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible

The `\1` is the replacement backreference that puts the contents of Group 1 into the result.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/JBsvh2):

```
s <- "xxx/yyy?utm_medium=display&utm_source=ogury&utm_campaign=TOTO&zzz=coco"
sub(".*[&?]utm_campaign=([^&]+).*", "\\1", s)
## => [1] "TOTO"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`(?:&utm_campaign=)(\w+)`

and use the *first group* captured

[Try it Online](https://regexr.com/3rm10)

Comment: Note that in case `utm_campaign` is the first query string param, it will have `?` in front, so `(?:&utm_campaign=)(\w+)` might not work in all cases. Besides, note that `(?:&utm_campaign=)` = `&utm_campaign=`.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `[[a-z]]+` however `TOTO` is uppercase, so not between 'a' and 'z'. You can update it to `[[A-Za-z]]+` to match any case letter.

**EDIT:** `[[A-Za-z]]+` will match any case letter, but will also match any '[' or ']' characters. If you do not wish to match these then you can change it to `[A-Za-z]+` to only match any case letters

Comment: The `[[A-Za-z]]+` matches any char from the  `[[A-Za-z]` bracket expression (any ASCII letter or `[`) and then matches one or more `]` chars (e.g. `[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]` like strings).

Comment: Yes, however this is how it was originally written so I assumed it was intended as such.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this error, I have edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex string that'll match the value of a `utm_campaign` parameter, regardless of its position in the query string.

```
(?<TOTO>(?<=utm_campaign=).*?(?=&|$))
```

Explanation:

- `?<TOTO>` captures the result into a `TOTO` key after the regex is executed
- `(?<=utm_campaign=)` is a look-behind that will ensure that the value is preceded by `utm_campaign=`

  - `.*?` will find the parameter value (i.e. `TOTO`). The reason for the `?` is lazy evaluation - it will only search until the next rule is matched (see point below)
  - `(?=&|$)` is a look-ahead that will match either an `&` or the end of the string (in the case that `utm_campaign` is the last parameter)